MOSFET Problem: How can I find Vbs?
Please help me understand this circuit. Right now I am only interested in how to find Vtp.
I need to find Vbs to find Vtp because everything else is given for me to complete the equation.
I think Vs = 0.5 and Vd = 2V, and that Vdd = 3V is somewhere to the left of the 2V but I don't think that's important for this part. Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere in my assumptions.
Where I am completely lost is that I am not sure where Vb is. So please someone help me with if I am right to think Vs = 0.5V and where Vb is so that I can find Vbs. Thank you


How do you make a distinction between source and drain in a PFET? Which one has a higher potential? Once you know the answer to that, you can assume the bulk terminal is held at $V_{DD}$ and arrive at your $V_{BS}$.

Jean Zhang - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY (More rules in the [tour] & [help])

In a PFET, convention is to select source as a higher voltage than drain, so thus source is 2V and drain is 0.5V? And Vbs = Vb - Vs = 3 - 2 = 1V? @a360pilot

@JeanZhang correct, and this would be in contrast to your initial assumption of $V_S = 0.5,\text{V}$ in the question. Since the source is below the bulk in this case, the source-bulk junction is further reverse biased, and $\vert V_{t_p} \vert $ will increase. You can probably post an answer to your question and compute the final values with this knowledge.
